# Separate appends with same remove method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, appendchild, removechild

So basically i'm appending two different thinds inside a table, with the same .parent().parent().remove() mehtod, in the first table it works, in the second it doesn't.

Any ideas?

Here is the code. http://jsfiddle.net/rzmA4/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#adauga_model').on('click', function(){
           $('#modele_adaugate').append('<tr><td><input type="file" name="model[]"></td><td><button class="remove" type="button">Remove</button></td></tr>');
      });
      $('#adauga_design').on('click', function(){
           $('#designuri_adaugate').append('<tr><td><input type="file" name="design[]"></td><td><button class="remove" type="button">Remove2</button></td></tr>');
      });
      $("td").on('click', '.remove', function() {
           $(this).parent().parent().remove();
           return false;
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is interesting that it worked on the first one at all, but you are adding an event listener to all TD elements when the document loads. However, you are creating new ones, which do not have the event listener.

I rewrote the script as follows to solve the problem:

```
 $("body").on('click', 'td .remove', function() {
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
      return false;
 });
```

As a bonus: Using `closest("tr")` is better than doing `parent().parent()`. When you do the latter and you later change your design, you might get a bug.